# How to hook a method in laravel dB

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a code below:

```
 $data = DB::table('blogs') 
        ->where('title', '=', $title);
```

Now, i want to add more methods after it has been initialized as above. i want to add something below so that additional where will be added to data.

```
 $input = TRUE;
 $data = DB::table('blogs') 
        ->where('title', '=', $title);

 if( $input ){
    $data->where('description','=', $description); //but then, this doesn't work
 }
```

i want to add more inside the if just like `orderby` , `where`. However, it is not working. 
What is the proper way to do this? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to Assign added condition to $data

Try Below Code

```
 $input = TRUE;
 $data = DB::table('blogs') 
        ->where('title', '=', $title);

 if( $input ){
   $data = $data->where('description','=', $description); 
 }
```

if need to add more condition :

```
$input1 = TRUE;

if( $input1 ){
       $data = $data->where('other_column','=', $other_var); 
     }
```

and in last fetch details by

```
$data = $data->get();
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this -

```
if(your_condition)
{
    $whereCondition = "table.description ='".$description."'";  // for any where condition
}
else
{
    $whereCondition = '1=1'; //for no where condition
}

$data = DB::table('blogs') 
          ->where('title', '=', $title)
          ->whereRaw($whereCondition)
          ->orderBy('table.column','DESC')
          ->get();
```

Hope this will helpful for you.